# How to concatenate two parts of an array to make a new array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Here I need to get a 2D array

```
x = np.zeros((10, 4))
y = np.ones((10, 4))
c = np.array([x[0:3, :], y[0:3, :]])
print c.shape  # I get (2, 3, 4)
np.reshape(c, (6, 4))
print c.shape  # I get (2, 3, 4)
```

I need to get a 2D array of 6 rows by 4 columns.

Comment: Have you tried any of the various [array combining methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)?

Comment: `np.reshape()` doesn't change the object in place.  It returns a new view of your array, but your code simply ignores the return value.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.concatenate((x[0:3,:], y[0:3,:]), axis=0)
```

Or

```
np.vstack((x[0:3,:],y[0:3,:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most concise solution is probably

```
c = np.r_[x[:3], y[:3]]
```

(The most concise solution isn't necessarily the most readable solution.)